# equating two 2d pointers-2d Arrays

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,},{9,10,11,12}};

    int **t = &A[0]; //I do this or **t = A,I guess both are equivalent


    printf("%d %p\n\n",*t,A[0]);

    return 0;

}
```

What I expected to happen:

Now t is a 2d pointer (pointer to pointer) holding the address of A[0] which in turn holds the address of A[0][0]. So *t should give me the value of A[0] ,that is the address of A[0][0] and **t should give me the value of A[0][0] ,which in this case is 1.

What I got:

*t gave the value of 1. And trying to find **t was not possible as it resulted in a Segmentation Fault.

Can anyone please tell why this is happening ?

I tried the following explanation,but not sure whether it is the "correct" explanation.
 t holds the address of A[0] ,but since A is an array and A[0] is an Array Pointer (which is "not exactly" a pointer),C doesn't allocate memory for pointer A or A[0] specially UNLIKE other pointer variables. It allocates memory only for the array as a whole . So the address of A[0] and A[0] (which is the address of A[0][0]) are essentially the same ,both belong under one roof and are not like 'separate' entities . As a result t in-turn indirectly holds  the address of A[0][0] and *t gives the value of A[0][0],which is 1.

Is the above explanation correct ?Kind of looks weird.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. An `int**` supposes a different memory layout than an `int[x][y]` has.

Comment: Isn't your compiler screaming at you in pain at this code?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm sure it does, just like the memory manager module of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

***Arrays are not pointers.***

Well, even more...

***Multiple-dimensional arrays are not double, triple, etc. pointers.***

So all you have is **wrong,** your program invokes undefined behavior **several times,** and there's **nothing you can expect.**

Given that arrays are contiguous in memory, you can rewrite your example like this:

```
int A[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,},{9,10,11,12}};
int *p = &A[0][0];

printf("%d %d %p\n", A[0][0], *p, (void *)p);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the following explanation,but not sure whether it is the "correct" explanation.

Not quite, but it's somewhat close.

> `t` holds the address of `A[0]` ,but since `A` is an array and `A[0]` is an Array Pointer

`A[0]` is an *array*, specifically, its type is `int[4]`.

> (which is "not exactly" a pointer),C doesn't allocate memory for pointer `A` or `A[0]` specially UNLIKE other pointer variables.

Arrays and pointers are fundamentally different types of entities. Don't confuse them.

The fact that in most circumstances an expression of type `array of T` is converted into a value of type `pointer to T` (pointing to the array's first element) sure contributes to the confusion, but one must not forget that it is a *conversion*. In particular, for higher-dimensional arrays, or arrays of arrays, the element type of the array is itself an array type, so the result of the conversion is a pointer to an array.

> It allocates memory only for the array as a whole. So the address of `A[0]` and `A[0]` (which is the address of `A[0][0]`) are essentially the same,

No, they are essentially different, one - `A[0]` - is an array, `int[4]`, the other - `&A[0]` - is a pointer to an array of four `int`, `int(*)[4]`. Neither is `&A[0][0]`.

But when `A[0]` is converted to a pointer to its first element, `&A[0][0]`, the resulting address usually is the same as the address of `A[0]` (usually, a pointer to an object holds the address of the byte with the lowest address belonging to the object, and since `A[0]` belongs to (is part of) the object `A`, the one with the lowest address, the first byte that is part of `A[0]` is the first byte that is part of `A`).

So `&A[0]` and `&A[0][0]` usually have the same representation, but one is an `int(*)[4]`, the other an `int*`.

> both belong under one roof and are not like 'separate' entities . As a result `t` in-turn indirectly holds the address of `A[0][0]` and `*t` gives the value of `A[0][0]`, which is 1.

That part is, apart from the type mismatch that makes dereferencing `t` undefined behaviour, more or less correct. Formally, the undefined behaviour allows anything to happen.

In practice, if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`, dereferencing `t` interprets the `int` 1 that is `A[0][0]` as an address, and if you print that as an `int` (yet another undefined behaviour), you get `1` printed. If `sizeof(int*) == 2*sizeof(int)`, as is common on 64-bit systems, dereferencing `t` would usually interpret the two `int`s `A[0][0]` and `A[0][1]` together as an address - `0x200000001` or `0x100000002` depending on endianness probably.